# Folland Theorem 1.14 extending premeasure to a measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

**1.14 Theorem** Let $\mathcal A \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ be an algebra, $\mu_0$ be a premeasure on $\mathcal A$, and $\mathcal{M}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$. There exists a measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{M}$ whose restriction to $\mathcal{A}$ is $\mu_0$, namely $\mu=\mu^\star|\mathcal{M}$ where $\mu^\star$ is given by (1.12). If $v$ is another measure on $\mathcal{M}$ that extends $\mu_0$, then $v(E)\leq \mu(E)$ for all $E\in \mathcal{M}$, with equality when $\mu(E)\leq \infty$. If $\mu_0$ is $\sigma$-finite, then $\mu$ is the unique extension of $\mu_0$ to a measure on $\mathcal{M}$.

My question is on the second assertion for which the proof reads:

As for the second assertion, if $E\in \mathcal{M}$ and $E\subset \bigcup_1^\infty A_j$ where $A_j\in \mathcal{A}$, then $v(E)\leq \sum_1^\infty v(A_j)=\sum_1^\infty \mu_0(A_j)$ whence $v(E)\leq \mu(E)$.

The only step I can see is that by monotonicity, we have that $v(E)\leq v(\bigcup_1^\infty A_j)$. I understand that $v=\mu_0$ on $\mathcal{A}$ however, how can I get to  $v(E)\leq \sum_1^\infty v(A_j)=\sum_1^\infty \mu_0(A_j)$  and moreover, why does this imply that $v(E) \leq \mu(E)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\nu (\bigcup A_j) \leq \sum \nu(A_j)$ for any measure $\nu$. $\nu (A_j)=\mu_0(A_j)$ because $A_j \in \mathcal A$. The last step follows from the definition of $\mu^{*}$ and the fact that $\mu^{*}(E)=\mu (E)$ because $E \in \mathcal M$.